ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit_algorithms'
I am doing the code migration from qiskit== 0.46.0 to qiskit==1.0
from qiskit.opflow import MatrixOp  

The above module works in qiskit==0.46.0. Its substitute in qiskit==1.0 is as below:
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp

The below module EfficientSU2 works in both the versions.
 from qiskit.circuit.library import EfficientSU2

However, the below modules are not working in qiskit==1.0 and giving me error.
from qiskit_algorithms.optimizers import COBYLA
from qiskit.algorithms import VQE

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit_algorithms'

Please suggest corrections for these modules as per qiskit==1.0.

Hi, I have 2 questions : first, when you tried to migrate from 0.x to 1.x, did you create a brand new environment for the change or did you upgrade within the same env? Second, did you try to install the package qiskit-algorithms? It's now a new package living outside of the core qiskit package so you would need to install it in addition to qiskit to run this code. If you didn't install the package you should try to install it first and see if it works! :)

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about quantum computing. In general, just because a question came up in the course of work in quantum computing does not automatically imply it is about quantum computing. For example, questions about misconfigured python search path, leaking dilution refrigerator, or burnout among lab colleagues, are not about quantum computing and hence do not belong on this site. This particular question belongs in qiskit's official support channels.

Thank you @Lena for the response.  Yes, I  created a new conda env for the qiskit==1.0. Seeing your comment, I have now installed qiskit-algorithms using the command pip install qiskit-algorithms. Please suggest any changes I need to make in my import statements for VQE and COBYLA?

Thank you @AdamZalcman for the response. Although this question has a limited scope but sometimes updates in software versions becomes  a quite difficult problem to solve.

The algorithms were moved out of qiskit into their own separate repository, and their use deprecated from qiskit and removed in 1.0 release. There is a migration guide here https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/migration-guides/qiskit-algorithms-module. You would need to install the new qiskit-algorithms package and change imports as the migration guide explains.

Thank you for the response @SteveWood for the response.

Thank you for the help @SteveWood. Still took me a lot of time to figure it out. The correct import statements are : from qiskit_algorithms import VQE
from qiskit_algorithms.optimizers import COBYLA
